# Is there a way to check if a menu option changed in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am currently working in a GUI using Python 3.6 and PyQt5, I have a menu bar with 3 menus, one of them is Called Settings in which the user can select the month they want to see, is there a way to check if the selected action changed instead of using

```
self.actionJanuary.isChecked()
```

Or

```
self.actionJanuary.triggered.connect()
```

Comment: Why do not you want to use the triggered signal?

Comment: @eyllanesc because I would have to use it 12 times and i don't want my code to be that long, I'm looking for a shorter way to do it.

Comment: I think you're doing it incorrectly, you could show your code and I'll tell you the optimal way to do it.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I have not coded yet but this is how i defined each month in my menu bar
`self.actionMarzo = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
self.actionMarzo.setCheckable(True)
self.actionMarzo.setObjectName("actionMarzo")
self.menuMes.addAction(self.actionEnero)
self.menuSettings.addAction(self.menuMes.menuAction())`

Comment: Has my solution worked for you?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you point out the problem are the many lines of code that you use because it seems that you are creating 12 `QAction`s, but the simplest thing is to iterate for it, the calendar module is used, on the other hand instead of connecting the `triggered` signal of the `QAction`s it can be used the `triggered` signal of the `QMenu` that returns the modified `QAction` as shown below:

```
import sys
import calendar
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        menu_months = self.menuBar().addMenu("Settings") 
        menu_months.triggered.connect(self.on_triggered)

        for i in range(1, 13):
            name = calendar.month_name[i]
            action = menu_months.addAction(name)
            action.setCheckable(True)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWidgets.QAction)
    def on_triggered(self, action):
        print("{} : {}".format(action.text(), action.isChecked()))

        # uncomment if you want to see the status of all actions
        """menu = self.sender()
        for action in menu.actions():
            print("{} : {}".format(action.text(), action.isChecked()))"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```